# Alert presented as sheet from JXA script never dismisses

Tags: javascript, macos, cocoa, applescript, javascript-automation

I’m trying present an alert as a sheet using JXA. It works as expected in AppleScript, but when running the equivalent JavaScript the sheet never dismisses.

To reproduce, run this in Automator with the “Run AppleScript” workflow:

```
use framework "Cocoa"
 
on show(title as string, msg as string)
    set alert to current application's NSAlert's new()
    tell alert
        its setMessageText:title
        its setInformativeText:(msg)
        its beginSheetModalForWindow:(current application's NSApp's mainWindow()) completionHandler:(missing value)
    end tell
end show
 
show("test", "test")
```

Then try running this in a different workflow with “Run JavaScript”:

```js
ObjC.import("Cocoa");
 
function show(title, msg) {
    let alert = $.NSAlert.new;
    alert.messageText = title;
    alert.informativeText = msg;
    alert.beginSheetModalForWindowCompletionHandler($.NSApp.mainWindow, null);
}
 
show("test", "test");
```

Is there a step I'm missing here? In the docs for `beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:`, it states:

> Note that `orderOut:` no longer needs to be called in the completion handler. If you don’t dismiss the alert, it will be done for you after the completion handler finishes.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsalert/1524296-beginsheetmodalforwindow

I'm running the latest version of macOS at the time of this writing, 11.1.

Answer (score 1):

No completion handler, no need **beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:** method. Use **runModal:** instead. Save following JXA code as application and run it.

```
ObjC.import("Cocoa");
 
function show(title, msg) {
    let alert = $.NSAlert.new;
    alert.messageText = title;
    alert.informativeText = msg;
    alert.runModal;
}
 
show("test", "test");
```

Using both methods together also works without throwing an error.

```
ObjC.import("Cocoa");
 
function show(title, msg) {
    let alert = $.NSAlert.new;
    alert.messageText = title;
    alert.informativeText = msg;
    alert.beginSheetModalForWindowCompletionHandler($.NSApp.mainWindow, null);
    alert.runModal;
}
 
show("test", "test");
```

Here is AppleScript Objective C application example which uses completion handler and 2 methods together. The same can be done with JavaScript Objective C.

```
use framework "Cocoa"
use scripting additions

on show(title as string, msg as string)
    set alert to current application's NSAlert's new()
    tell alert
        its setMessageText:title
        its setInformativeText:(msg)
        its beginSheetModalForWindow:(current application's NSApp's mainWindow()) completionHandler:(my completionHandler())
        its runModal()
    end tell
end show

on completionHandler()
    repeat 5 times
        display dialog (time string of (current date)) giving up after 1
        delay 1
    end repeat
end completionHandler

show("test", "test")
```

Comment: `beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:` is not deprecated - it just uses a block for the completion handler.

Comment: @red_menace. You are right. It isn't deprecated. I upvoted your fair  comment and updated my answer.